# How to select element as active and inactive in vue-moveable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on some editor which has text adding feature. There I'm using vue-moveable for moving text elements on a div. By default element is selected but I want to unselect that element when clicked outside of that element as there will be multiple text elements on that div. I'm have looked into their sandbox code as well as their API docs but didn't found any solution to this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update: Element is selected by default so blue border is shown with resize features so this should only be shown when clicked on that element.

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-zthzj?fontsize=14&file=/src/App.vue